# How to eliminate last digit from each of the top lines

Tags: python, file

> Sequence 1.1.1  ATGCGCGCGATAAGGCGCTA
>       ATATTATAGCGCGCGCGCGGATATATATATATATATATATT
>   Sequence 1.2.2  ATATGCGCGCGCGCGCGGCG
>       ACCCCGCGCGCGCGCGGCGCGATATATATATATATATATATT
>   Sequence 2.1.1  ATTCGCGCGAGTATAGCGGCG

NOW,I would like to remove the last digit from each of the line that starts with '>'. For example, in this first line, i would like to remove '.1' (rightmost) and in second instance i would like to remove '.2' and then write the rest of the file to a new file. Thanks,

Comment: Hey! That's *my* DNA!

Comment: lots of good pythonic answers... nice!

Comment: Are you involved in a Jurassic Park kind of project?

Comment: This will get closed.  Just edit your other question.

Comment: This looks a LOT like a homework I had to do. Are you from quebec by any chance ;)

Answer (score 7):

```
import fileinput
import re

for line in fileinput.input(inplace=True, backup='.bak'):
  line = line.rstrip()
  if line.startswith('>'):
    line = re.sub(r'\.\d$', '', line)
  print line
```

many details can be changed depending on details of the processing you want, which you have not clearly communicated, but this is the general idea.

Comment: Cool use of fileinput. I'd never heard of this module.

Comment: So Arshan, accept an answer that's helped you most -- that's fundamental StackOverflow etiquette!

Comment: @hughdbrown, glad you liked it -- it's a great module especially for "pseudo-inplace" alteration of textfiles.

Answer (score 4):

```
if line.startswith('>Sequence'):
  line = line[:-2] # trim 2 characters from the end of the string
```

or if there could be more than one digit after the period:

```
if line.startswith('>Sequence'):
  dot_pos = line.rfind('.') # find position of rightmost period
  line = line[:dot_pos] # truncate upto but not including the dot
```

**Edit for if the sequence occurs on the same line as >Sequence**

If we know that there will always be only 1 digit to remove we can cut out the period and the digit with:

```
line = line[:13] + line[15:]
```

This is using a feature of Python called *slices*. The indexes are zero-based and exclusive for the end of the range so `line[0:13]` will give us the first 13 characters of `line`. Except that if we want to start at the beginning the 0 is optional so `line[:13]` does the same thing. Similarly `line[15:]` gives us the substring starting at character 15 to the end of the string.

Comment: What to do if I have this case
>Sequence 1.1.1 atgcgcgcgatatat
ashhshshsh
So now I only have to remove ".1" but not a single digit on either the right side or left side of it, just the last number ".1" or whatever it is. Thanks

Comment: Are you saying the atgcgcgcgatatat is on the same line as >Sequence 1.1.1 or it that just the way your comment has formatted? Please explain a bit more what you mean

Comment: Sure. Yes you interpreted right. atgcgcgatga sequence is on the same line. So, in this case now I have to remove last digit from the series of digits. One thing is sure that this last digit will always be present on 15th index on every line starting with '>'.

Comment: @Arshan please include all possible formattings in your question

Comment: Here is the detailed question.
>Sequence 1.1.1 atatatccchhchc
asjssjsjjsjsjsjsj
>Sequence 1.2.2 atatatatatatata
ssdjdjdjfjfjfjjjgjg
>Sequence 1.2.1 atatatatatat
atatatatatatatatatat

Now, I have to remove last digit from every line that starts with '>'. Like in case of first line, I have to remove '.1' (rightmost) and in second case, I have to remove '.2' (rightmost).

Comment: please consider that every line that starts with '>' is a new line.

Comment: @Arshan you can use the 'edit' link to update and clarify your question. Then you can use all the formatting which is not available in comments.

Answer (score 4):

```
import re
trimmedtext = re.sub(r'(\d+\.\d+)\.\d', '$1', text)
```

Should do it. Somewhat simpler than searching for start characters (and it won't effect your DNA chains)

Comment: looks great but sorry could not understood your code. I started python yesterday so could you be very kind to start with the the opening of file? Thanks.

Comment: @Arshan: Have you read the Python tutorial yet?  It should help you understand the basic steps like reading files and iterating through lines to give you the context for using this solution.

Comment: Oli is using what is called a regular expression for performing substitution on the text. These patterns such as (\d+\.\d+)\.\d are a general concept and not specific to Python.

Comment: Yes I know how to open, read and write file. But not sure about iterating lines in a file.

Comment: You don't *need* to iterate lines with this. You can if you want to but you can just chuck the whole file through with `open('filename').read()`. And yes, my code before is based on the regex library built into python. Regex is something worth learning as it's very useful for doing operations like this. It's also great for input validation.

Answer (score 2):

map `"".join(line.split('.')[:-1])` to each line of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short script. Run it like: `script [filename to clean]`. Lots of error handling omitted.

It operates using generators, so it should work fine on huge files as well.

```
import sys
import os

def clean_line(line):
    if line.startswith(">"):
        return line.rstrip()[:-2]
    else:
        return line.rstrip()

def clean(input):
    for line in input:
        yield clean_line(line)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    filename = sys.argv[1]

    print "Cleaning %s; output to %s.." % (filename, filename + ".clean")

    input = None
    output = None
    try:
        input = open(filename, "r")
        output = open(filename + ".clean", "w")
        for line in clean(input):
            output.write(line + os.linesep)
            print ": " + line
    except:
        input.close()
        if output != None:
            output.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

input_file = open('in')
output_file = open('out', 'w')

for line in input_file:
    line = re.sub(r'(\d+[.]\d+)[.]\d+', r'\1', line)
    output_file.write(line)
```

Comment: One issue left please. It is working when I have 1.9.1 etc so it removes last digit but when I have 2.10.1, it does not work.

Comment: I fixed it so it works with numbers with more than one digit.